# Custom Transformer for ML pipelines

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science

I am attempting to write a custom transformer for the first time. My aim is to code a transformer class similar that utilizes the StandardScaler(). Here is a link to the dataset - https://www.kaggle.com/iabhishekofficial/mobile-price-classification/kernels
. All my features are numerical (in the first look) but some features have distinct values and some have continuous vales. So I figured that distinct values are mapped and hence they are actually categorical features. These features will lose their meaning if standardized.
So my aim is to create a custom transformer that figures out which input features are numerical and which are categorical and then it should standardize the numerical features using StandardScaler class provided by SK learn.

Here is the code:

```
#Custom transformer to standardize the continuous numerical values
class CustomNormalizer(BaseEstimator,TransformerMixin):

    #Class Constructor
    def __init__(self,features,copy=True,with_mean=True,with_std=True):
        self.features = features
        self.scaler = StandardScaler(copy,with_mean,with_std)

    #Return the fit features
    def fit( self, X, y = None ):
        return self

    # Custom transformer 
    def transform(self, X, y = None):
        categorical_feature_names = []
        numerical_feature_names = []

        unique_entries = pd.DataFrame(X[self.features].nunique(), columns = ['values']).T
        for feature in unique_entries.columns:
            if(unique_entries.loc["values", feature] == 2):
                categorical_feature_names.append(feature)
            else:
                numerical_feature_names.append(feature)

        numerical_features_scaled = self.scaler.fit_transform(X[numerical_feature_names])
        numerical_features = pd.DataFrame(numerical_features_scaled, columns = numerical_feature_names) 

        categorical_features = X.drop(numerical_feature_names, axis = 1)

        return categorical_features.join(numerical_features)
```

Then I instantiate this class and fit and transform the dataset:

```
norm = CustomNormalizer(inputs.columns.values)
norm.fit(X_train, y_train)
norm.transform(X_train, y_train)
```

The issue is that as outcome I preserved the categorical features but the numerical features are giving a lot of NaN (missing values). I am unable to figure out why this is happening.

DataFrame Before:
[image]

DataFrame After:
[image]

Comment: I have figured out that if I pass the entire inputs and target for fit and transform, there won't be any missing values. Missing values appear when I pass X_train and X_test!

Comment: But the issue is that I want to pass the train data only and not the entire dataset.